# c++ stl const iterator and const pointer

Tags: c++, constants, shared-ptr, const-iterator

I'm a little confuse about meaning of this const keyword
I have a class like this

```
class ClassA {
public:
    typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<ClassA> ptr;
    typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<const ClassA> const_ptr;
    void oper() const;
    void oper();
private:
    .....
};

int main()
{
    std::list<ClassA::const_ptr> const_list;
    .....
    for(std::list<ClassA::const_ptr>::iterator it = const_list.begin();\
    it != const_list.end(); it++)
    {
        (*it)->oper();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I already get const version of oper() from the code above. So I can't imagine what will I get if I change std::list::iterator to std::list::const_iterator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your situation is a bit confusing because there are two levels of indirection (the iterator and the smart pointer), with `const` being applicable in some way to any of them (and also to the referenced object).

You can apply `const`:

- to the object itself; this means that it cannot be modified;
- to the smart pointer; this means that the smart pointer cannot be modified, e.g. cannot be reseated via `reset`;
- in some sense to the iterator, using a `const_iterator`; this means that it will yield a `const` reference to the object it refers (=>the smart pointer) and that it cannot be used to modify the sequence it refers to.

---

Expanding a little:

Remember that a `const shared_ptr<const ClassA>&` (which is what you get by dereferencing a `const_iterator`) is different from  a `shared_ptr<const ClassA>&` (which you get from a normal `iterator`): although on both you cannot modify the pointed object (due to the fact that `shared_ptr` refers to a `const ClassA`), on the `const` one you cannot modify the `shared_ptr` itself, which e.g. means that you can't `reset` it to point to another object, you cannot assign another `shared_ptr` to it, ...

Remember also that `const` versions of iterators, beside yielding a `const` reference to what they refer to, also disallow modifying the container through them (e.g. you cannot `erase` an element via a `const_iterator`).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you understand what `void oper() const` in `class ClassA` means: In particular, it means that means is that `ClassA::oper()` is not allowed to modify any members of `ClassA`.

Which has little baring on your choice of iterator or const_iterator, that choice would have different implications.

Comment: I have to use     (*it)->oper() since the list is holding smart pointer to the object not the object.

Comment: oh silly me.. yah i see that now in the for loop but still the main point still applies